# Run .bash_profile script at login

Tags: gnome, bash, login, scripts, kiosk

i'm working on a deb package that allows the administrator to create another account and run that account automatically in kiosk mode. I created the user, specified a shortkey and put that in a hidden file, and created a .bash_profile script on the admin account that i copy to the new user's home folder.

This is the script i'm running to create the files and specify the shortkey:

```
#!/bin/bash
basis="Primary + Alt + "
shortkey=`zenity --entry --text "Your shortkey will be a combination of <Primary> + <Alt> + a letter\n\n Specify your letter!"`

while [[ $shortkey = *[^A-Z]* ]];
        do
                zenity --warning --text "Input incorrect\n\nTry again"
                shortkey=`zenity --entry --text "Your shortkey will be a combination of <Primary> + <Alt> + a letter\n\n Specify your letter!"`

done
        basis="$basis$shortkey"
zenity --info --text "$basis" --title="Your shortkey"

touch kiosk/kiosk-0.1/.mykey
echo "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close [$basis]" > kiosk/kiosk-0.1/.mykey

user=$(cat kiosk/kiosk-0.1/.username)
keys=$(cat kiosk/kiosk-0.1/keys)
content=$(cat kiosk/kiosk-0.1/.mykey)

touch kiosk/kiosk-0.1/.bash_profile
echo "#!/bin/bash" >> .bash_profile
echo "" >> .bash_profile
echo $keys >> .bash_profile
echo $content >> .bash_profile
chmod +x .bash_profile
chown $user .bash_profile
mv '.bash_profile' /home/$user
```

That content that is copied to .bash_profile contains code to disable all the keys from the interface like:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move []
```

Now I only added a line to start the chromium browser to the right website

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser www.google.be --kiosk --no-default-browser-check --disable-translate
```

I also changed the owner of the .bash_profile script to the account user and made it executable before I copied it to the new users home folder.

Now when i login on the new user, this script does nothing. Can anyone see where i'm wrong of help me finding the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that `.bash_profile` is not read when you do a graphical login. It is a bash-specific file, it's read when you start a login shell and I very much doubt it will ever be read on graphical login.

You would have a better chance using `~/.profile` instead which is i) read by most login shells, not only bash, so you're not limiting your user to a specific shell and ii) far more likely to be read by a graphical login.

I just checked this and `.profile` is indeed read on Ubuntu 13.04 when you log in graphically. However, you cannot assume that will always be the case. For more details see Gilles's excellent answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/183980/151431).

Now, a couple of minor points. There is no need for `touch`, `echo "foo" >> bar` will create the file `bar` if it doesn't exist and append to it if it does. Also, there is no need for `.bash_profile` to be executable, the file is sourced, not run. I don't know if that would cause problems but it might.

Finally, the file's group will be root, not the user's. Again, not sure if this is a problem but you may as well add this to your script:

```
chown $user:$user .profile
```

Note that `.profile` [is ignored by bash](https://superuser.com/a/695397/151431) if a file called `~/.bash_profile` exists. This should not affect graphical logins but may cause unexpected behavior when logging in from the command line.

Comment: i'm using the ~/.profile file now, but is it possible to call a executable script in this file? I'm trying to run my bash script with 'bash disable.sh &' but the login still happens as usual

Comment: @Gijs depends on many things. If this makes your firefox load, please ask a new question about the next issue. Make sure to show what `disable.sh` is. Also, make sure you call the script with its full path,. for example `/home/foo/scripts/disable.sh`.